# iphone - not loading ~ipad image

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have 3 images on the same place on my app's bundle: "image~iphone.png", "image@2x~iphone.png" and "image~ipad.png".

when I do

```
UIImage *imageU = [UIImage imageNamed:[[NSBundle mainBundle]  pathForResource:@"image"
ofType:@"png"]];
```

BOth, the iPhone and iPhone 4 hires versions load fine, but not the ipad image. When I run on iPad, I get nil on imageU.

Yes, the image is there, the name is correct (iphone~ipad.png).

Why is that? any clues?

thanks.

Comment: Why not just use `UIImage *imageU = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];`?

Comment: good question. This is not working in my project. I have to give the full path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that the solution for that is: do not use any extension on the iPad images. This tilde trick is not working for iPad. One more buggy stuff that makes us waste time.

Answer (score 0):

Possible daft attempt, but is the ipad image copied into the correct target when you add it as a resource? By that, I mean - of you right click the image and get info, does it have the iPad ticked as it's target?

Comment: yes. Checked them out again now. All perfectly assigned to the correct target.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem with launch images. Despite what the docs say, naming a file with a ~ipad suffix doesn't do anything. You need to set the `UILaunchImageFile~ipad` key and use a separate name for your launch images on iPad, e.g., DefaultiPad.png and DefaultiPad-Landscape.png, then make sure to just set `UILaunchImageFile~ipad` to `DefaultiPad` (no .png suffix) and it will pick up the variants correctly.

Comment: how is this related? is is talking about [UIImage imageNamed:], not launch images.

Answer (score -1):

image "image~ipad.png" will show HD quality on iPad because in ios 5.1 "~ipad.png" is used to show HD quality image of resolution 2048*2048.Test this naming conservation on  iPad,it will work.

Comment: Isn't he saying in his question exactly that it *doesn't* work for him?