# how will existing apps look on ipad3 or high resolution ipad

Tags: ipad, app-store, retina-display

has someone tried running existing ipad apps on new released version of ipad? how will the existing apps behave in ipad3?

whether all existing ipad apps run on ipad3 as well without any changes or do they necessary need an upgrade with the high resolution images and icons? if existing apps will run, will they look similar to how iphone apps run on ipad (a smaller screen size with option to scale them to ipad resolution).

Comment: The question should be code related.

Comment: A bit hard to tell, seeing as the iPad 3 isn't launched until Friday.

Comment: They would look fairly mediocre at first, and then eventually Apple would make adding retina graphics a requirement like they recently did with retina for iPhones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried apps on the iPad 3, because it still hasn't been released, but I guess it'll be like running iPhone apps without Retina support on a device with the Retina display, i.e. they will work but will look ugly and pixelated. An update with high resolution artwork wouldn't be necessary but definitely recommended.

Comment: Any idea if the same method as in iphone(3 vs retina) will be followed. what i mean to say is will the same code with only image change of @2x do the trick?

Comment: Hard to say, but maybe, yeah. Can't you just wait until Friday? :)

Comment: I could wait until Friday but a customer is sitting on my head :) And yes the same thing will work. Found it here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611061/how-to-support-both-ipad-and-iphone-retina-graphics-in-universal-apps