# what is image size(resolution) for iPad 3 application development?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, ipad-3

As we know iPad 3 have 2048×1536 resolution.
for iPhone 4 with retina display we put big image with name @2X and one normal image in our bundle.

so for iPad 3 application development we also need to put two images one is normal size and other with big size with @2X name..?

Any one know please reply.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/9611061/716216

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With the iPad 3, you also simply need to name your retina images `foo@2x.png`. It needs to be exactly two times the resolution of the corresponding `foo.png`. So, say `foo.png` is 10x10, then your `foo@2x.png` needs to be 20x20.

You can also make version specifically for iPhone/iPod or iPad and iOS will automatically chose the correct version. For this, you can use the `~iphone` and `~ipad` modifiers:

- `foo.png` for all devices with non-retina display
- `foo~iphone.png` specifically for iPhone/iPod non-retina
- `foo~ipad.png` specifically for iPad non-retina
- `foo@2x.png` for all devices with retina display
- `foo@2x~iphone.png` specifically for iPhone/iPad retina
- `foo@2x~ipad.png` specifically for iPad retina

You can mix them in any combination, as long as there's always a version for all your supported devices (if you're doing an iPad-only app there's no need to provide images for iPhone, of course). So it's OK to provide for example `foo~iphone.png`, `foo~ipad.png` and then `foo@2x.png`.

Comment: What about with the new iPhone graphics size... where does it fit into all this?

Comment: Which new graphic size? Do you mean the iPhone 5? It does not have a new "modifier" for the images (except for the splash screen which must be named `Default-568h@2x.png`). If you need different images on iPhone 5, you must do this manually in your code yourself at the moment.

Comment: So the iphone 5 would probably use the @2x~iphone images unless you manually check if its iphone 5 and force a different image?

Comment: The iPhone 5 will try to load images in the following order: `foo@2x~iphone`, `foo@2x`, `foo~iphone`, `foo`. Yes, if you need to have a different image on iPhone 5 you will have to manually check whether you're on an iPhone 5 and load a different image (`bar*`).

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be "image~ipad" & "image@2x~ipad" for iPad with Retina Display if you are writing a Universal app (since "image" & "image@2x" are for iPhone/iPod images).

Otherwise I guess "image" & "image@2x" is OK.

Refer to [How to support both iPad and iPhone retina graphics in universal apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611061/how-to-support-both-ipad-and-iphone-retina-graphics-in-universal-apps) .