# Loading different images for iPhone and iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiimage

I have read this post: [How to support both iPad and iPhone retina graphics in universal apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611061/how-to-support-both-ipad-and-iphone-retina-graphics-in-universal-apps) and know that all I need to place ~ipad at the back of the name of the image to have it read properly. I have done this.

The problem is that the image appears correctly in the simulator. I can see that it reading the correct image from the size. But same image is appears as the iPhone Version in the device. Not sure why this is happening.

Need some guidance on this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time I've had the proper image in the simulator, and image not showing up on the device, its been the same thing:  UpperCase lowerCase mismatch on the name.  i.e. You are asking for myPicture of type png, and your file is named MyPicture.png.

The simulator doesn't mind the case difference, but the device won't recognize the improper name.