# iOS image size for iPhone and iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiimage

I am developing universal app for iOS,

I am using `Autolayout` feature in my app,

I have one doubt:

I want to apply background image in my app, 
**How many background image i will have to make ??**
and what will be the naming conventions of the images ?
so that iPhone automatically takes corresponding images according to device.

Like we gives on launch images, `default@2x.png`, `Default-568h@2x.png`, `Default-Portrait@2x.png` and device automatically understands it's corresponding images.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to support both iPad and iPhone retina graphics in universal apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611061/how-to-support-both-ipad-and-iphone-retina-graphics-in-universal-apps)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need 2 types of images for `iphone` and `ipad`.

For `ipad` you just need to add `~ipad` before `.png`. 
e.g. `image.png` for `iphone` and `image~ipad.png` for `ipad`.

Do the same for Retina display images also.

e.g.

`iPhone Retina`: image@2x.png

`iPad Retina`: image@2x~ipad.png

Comment: Use dimension that fits iPhone 5 and if you are putting image through `storyboard` or `xib`, then it will fit automatically.

Comment: For iPhone again we have 2 type of resolution one for iPhone 4S and other for 5. what will be the resolution of `image@2x.png` ?

Comment: what you say, i need to supply only one image for iphone with `640*1136` resolution ?? and it will compress that image in iPhone 4s ??

Comment: If you are adding it with `storyboard/xib` and if your `640x1136` is going to fit in `320x558` screen, then it will automatically shrink for `iphone 4` resolution also. I Think so. Why dont you give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

What should help in your case is [Asset Catalogs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html), which are by far the best way to manage assets for multiple devices.

Comment: This is a start of a really good answer. Unfortunately, it is incomplete, because it lacks explicit mention of what OP's asking about . If you could mention that (1) asset catalogs provide compartments for device-specific images, and (2) show a short code snippet that pulls a device-specific image from a resource managed through an asset catalog, your answer would be a lot better. Thanks!